# Javascript to check if center of map has moved not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, google-maps, mobile

I'm working on a project that uses the google maps api. One feature I want users to have is to be ability to add a marker with a long press/click, but only if the map hasn't moved (i.e. the center has stayed the same).

```
//event listener
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousedown', function(event){
  //current center
  var centerPoint = map.getCenter();
  var latLng = event.latLng;

  //timeout function
  var counter = setTimeout(function(){
    //function called
    setPressedLocationMarker(latLng, centerPoint);
  }, 1500);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseup', function(){
    clearTimeout(counter)
  });
});


//function in question
function setPressedLocationMarker(latLng, centerPoint) {
  if (centerPoint == map.getCenter()) {
    //DO STUFF
  }
}
```

To do this I put in an event listener for a mousedown event that gets the current center, and starts a Timeout. If the timeout completes without them releasing then it will call a function that first checks the current center of the map against the one set at the start of the event, if they're the same set a marker, else do nothing.

This works fine on my desktop but always reads the centers as being the same on my phone and I can't figure out why.

Any ideas why this might work on desktop but not on mobile?

Answer (score 1):

You should intercept

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function(){
    // set a  global var for avoid the adding of the marker 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I added that in but it still only works on desktop. Can't quite tell but I'm not sure if the Google Maps API registers a change in center until you release your finger for mobile, even though it registers it immediately on desktop

Answer (score 0):

So it appears the Google Maps API is a little counterintuitive when it comes to mobile vs desktop. For desktop it will register a change in center as soon as the map is moved, however it won't register it until after you lift your finger for mobile. To get around this I end up using a 'drag' listener since it does register that immediately on both platforms

```
sameCenter = true;
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function(){
  sameCenter = false;
});
```

Thanks to @scaisEdge for the initial idea.